# A function whose domain equals the set of real numbers and whose range equals the set of integers

Tags: functions

How would I find a function like this? Essentially, I need a function $f(x)$ such that $x$ can be any real number and $f(x)$ must only be contained in the set of all of the integers. I can't figure out what it would even look like.

All the other problems in the section were easy which makes me think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Greatest integer function?

Comment: The IVT guarantees that if the function is continuous and includes two distinct integers in its range, then the range cannot be solely integers.

Comment: If you only want $f(x)$ to be *contained* in the set of all integers, then of course a constant function will do (e.g., $f(x)\equiv 0$).

Comment: I Think the OP does not asks for a continuous function.

Comment: The function does not need to be continuous but its range needs to contain all integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are some examples of such functions.
$$\text{floor}(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor:=\max\{m\in\mathbb{Z}~\mid~m\leq x\}$$

$$\text{ceil}(x) = \lceil x\rceil:=\min\{n\in\mathbb{Z}~\mid~n\geq x\}$$

Try to graph the above two functions, you will understand them better.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious function was already given in the first comment, but many others can be easily constructed. Take for example $f(x) =\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Z\\ 0 &\text{ if } x\not\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

You can Give many Functions like Greatest integer function, Before that convince yourself that $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{a \in Z}[a,a+1)$$ and given any $x \in \mathbb{R}  ,\exists! a \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $x \in [a,a+1)$

Now define $f:\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{a \in Z}[a,a+1)\to \mathbb{Z}$ as $f(x)= a$,

The range of the function $f$ is clearly all of $\mathbb{Z}$.

using this you can create many functions, but there does not exist a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{Z}$ because it will contradict the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Anyone downvoted Kindly give the reason, So I can learn what is wrong with the solution. Thank you..:)